# How to find out a node's comment status (open, closed) from node ID?

Tags: 7, views, comments, forms

Having a view of comment fields here that is embedded into another view via [Views Field View](https://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module. The comment view has a contextual filter: the nid. Works quite nice.

Now I want to hide the view if comments ain't allowed (per node). Of course I have the node's ID as $argument. How can I check the comment status from that to specify the validate criteria?

Comment: $node = node_load($argument); 
$result = $node->comment;
if $result is 1 then comment status is closed. if it is 2 then status is open

Comment: 0 = closed, 1 = read only, 2 = read/write

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code should do the trick:

```
$node = node_load($argument); // load the node object based on the nid
if($node->comment == COMMENT_NODE_CLOSED) {
  // comments are closed - hide the view
}
```

There are 3 constants that define the different comment states:

- [`COMMENT_NODE_HIDDEN`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/constant/COMMENT_NODE_HIDDEN/7)
- [`COMMENT_NODE_CLOSED`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/constant/COMMENT_NODE_CLOSED/7)
- [`COMMENT_NODE_OPEN`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/constant/COMMENT_NODE_OPEN/7)

For more information see the [Node object reference](https://drupal.org/node/49768).

Comment: I just updated that page on drupal.org.  There are constants for this: COMMENT_NODE_HIDDEN, COMMENT_NODE_CLOSED, and COMMENT_NODE_OPEN.